# Layout inside Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, awt

I have a JPanel with a vertical BoxLayout, for one element i want to be able to use another BoxLayout which places elements horisontally.
The code will explain what i'm trying to do:

```
private void prepareGUI() {
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 0, 20, 0));
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Downloading");
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblTitle.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    add(lblTitle);

    Component verticalStrut = Box.createVerticalStrut(20);
    add(verticalStrut);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setBorder(null);
    progressBar.setValue(50);

    Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 25);
    progressBar.setMinimumSize(size);
    progressBar.setMaximumSize(size);
    progressBar.setPreferredSize(size);
    add(progressBar);

    BoxLayout textLayout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    JLabel lblTest_1 = new JLabel("Test 1!");
    textLayout.add(lblTest_1);

    JLabel lblTest_2 = new JLabel("Test 2!");
    textLayout.add(lblTest_2);

    add(textLayout);
}
```

Now obviously this isn't possible as BoxLayout isn't a Container (It even asks for the container to be linked to on construction.
My question is what is the best way to achieve what i want? Should i create another JPanel and put that inside the first JPanel? I was thinking that but it seems a little too complicated, there must be a simpler way?

Comment: the best way - is to take a pencil and paper and draw.

Comment: as an aside: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BoxLayout` is not a container, it's a LayoutManager, so, components can't be added to `BoxLayout` since box layout is not inheriting anything from abstract class `Component`, it's will add to some container like `JPanel` or frame's container....

So, it's wrong to say:

```
 textLayout.add(lblTest_1);
```

Or even

```
add(textLayout);
```

Because this method addes a component to the frame's container, and `BoxLayout` is not a component.

---

> Should i create another JPanel and put that inside the first JPanel?

Except what you did and avoiding `null` layout, you're free to do anything, as, design is upon to you, as far as I am preferring multiple panels if wanted.